# sqoop export local csv to MySQL error on mapreduce

Tags: mysql, csv, hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop

I was trying to export a local csv file to MySQL table "test":

```
$ sqoop export -fs local -jt local --connect jdbc:mysql://172.16.21.64:3306/cf_ae07c762_41a9_4b46_af6c_a29ecb050204 --username username --password password --table test --export-dir file:///home/username/test.csv
```

However, I got a strange error saying `mapreduce.tar.gz` not found:

```
Warning: /usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
17/04/07 14:22:14 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.5.0.0-1245
17/04/07 14:22:14 WARN fs.FileSystem: "local" is a deprecated filesystem name. Use "file:///" instead.
17/04/07 14:22:14 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
17/04/07 14:22:15 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
17/04/07 14:22:15 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
17/04/07 14:22:15 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `test2` AS t LIMIT 1
17/04/07 14:22:15 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `test2` AS t LIMIT 1
17/04/07 14:22:15 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-bedrock/compile/009603476b0dfc767b1b94c0607bf6fa/test2.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
17/04/07 14:22:17 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-bedrock/compile/009603476b0dfc767b1b94c0607bf6fa/test2.jar
17/04/07 14:22:17 INFO mapreduce.ExportJobBase: Beginning export of test2
17/04/07 14:22:17 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
17/04/07 14:22:17 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Encountered IOException running export job: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/hdp/apps/2.5.0.0-1245/mapreduce/mapreduce.tar.gz does not exist
```

The file is however available at my local machine:

```
/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/hadoop/mapreduce.tar.gz

/data/hadoop/yarn/local/filecache/13/mapreduce.tar.gz
```

Anyone knows what is the issue? I was just following this guide:

http://ingest.tips/2015/02/06/use-sqoop-transfer-csv-data-local-filesystem-relational-database/

Comment: The `export` command is fine, the problem is with this location `/hdp/apps/2.5.0.0-1245/mapreduce/mapreduce.tar.gz`. You have to find from where Sqoop is picking up this path which is incorrect.

Comment: Yeah that is the hard part because I cannot figure out how to chase that path variable at all. Where are the potential areas to look for?

Comment: Think I have found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `mapreduce.application.framework.path` has this value `/hdp/apps/2.5.0.0-1245/mapreduce/mapreduce.tar.gz` set in `mapred-site.xml`. This is the path for MapReduce framework archive and points to the file in HDFS.

Here, Sqoop being is triggered with `-fs local` this property needs to be set with a LocalFS path. Try overriding this property value with the local path of the mapreduce archive file.

```
$ sqoop export -fs local -jt local -D 'mapreduce.application.framework.path=/usr/hdp/2.5.0.0-1245/hadoop/mapreduce.tar.gz' --connect jdbc:mysql://172.16.21.64:3306/cf_ae07c762_41a9_4b46_af6c_a29ecb050204 --username username --password password --table test --export-dir file:///home/username/test.csv
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But another follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328725/sqoop-export-to-mysql-export-job-failed-tool-exporttool-but-got-records